# How to map multiple objects having two identical values and one different value to one object with list of those different values?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have an object called `RawCarEnumData` having 3 enums:

```
public class RawCarEnumData {

    private BrandEnum brand;
    private ModelEnum model;
    private ColorEnum color;

    //getters, setters, constructors

}
```

and an object `CarEnumData` having 2 enums and a list of enums:

```
public class CarEnumData {

    private BrandEnum brand;
    private ModelEnum model;
    private List<ColorEnum> colors;

    //getters, setters, constructors

}
```

Now I have a list of `RawCarEnumData` objects:

```
List<RawCarEnumData> rawCarEnumDataList = List.of(
    new RawCarEnumData(BrandEnum.FORD, ModelEnum.FIESTA, ColorEnum.RED),
    new RawCarEnumData(BrandEnum.FORD, ModelEnum.FIESTA, ColorEnum.BLUE),
    new RawCarEnumData(BrandEnum.FORD, ModelEnum.FIESTA, ColorEnum.YELLOW),
    new RawCarEnumData(BrandEnum.FORD, ModelEnum.FOCUS, ColorEnum.YELLOW)
}
```

Now I want to use stream API to map the `List<RawCarEnumData>` to `List<CarEnumData>` so the final output will look like this:

```
List<CarEnumData> carEnumData:
    - CarEnumData(BrandEnum.FORD, ModelEnum.FIESTA, List.of(ColorEnum.RED, ColorEnum.BLUE, ColorEnum.YELLOW))
    - CarEnumData(BrandEnum.FORD, ModelEnum.FOCUS, List.of(ColorEnum.YELLOW))
```

I have tried a few things but without success. How can this be achieved? Is this even possible?

Comment: if there is 2 identical cars in rawCarEnumDataList , for example two red Ford Fiesta, would the resulting list have List.of(ColorEnum.RED, ColorEnum.RED) or only just one time the color red then?

Comment: The assumption is that that a situation where two identical cars will be in this list will NEVER occur, but as Your question is very good - the result should contain only ONE car of that color, so two identical cars in `rawCarEnumDataList` will result in only ONE car in `carEnumData` list

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a Java question but I like to provide a Kotlin answer. It might help you come up with a Java solution or you might even want to include the Kotlin solution in your project since it should be interoperable with Java. The following code seems to do what you would like:

```
fun main() {
    val rawCarEnumDataList = listOf(
        RawCarEnumData(BrandEnum.FORD, ModelEnum.FIESTA, ColorEnum.RED),
        RawCarEnumData(BrandEnum.FORD, ModelEnum.FIESTA, ColorEnum.BLUE),
        RawCarEnumData(BrandEnum.FORD, ModelEnum.FIESTA, ColorEnum.YELLOW),
        RawCarEnumData(BrandEnum.FORD, ModelEnum.FOCUS, ColorEnum.YELLOW)
    )
    
    val carEnumData = rawCarEnumDataList
        .groupBy { Pair(it.brand, it.model) }
        .values.map { cars -> CarEnumData(cars.first().brand,cars.first().model, cars.map { it.color }.distinct()) }

    print(carEnumData)
    // prints [CarEnumData(brand=FORD, model=FIESTA, colors=[RED, BLUE, YELLOW]), CarEnumData(brand=FORD, model=FOCUS, colors=[YELLOW])]
}

data class RawCarEnumData(
    val brand: BrandEnum,
    val model: ModelEnum,
    val color: ColorEnum
)

data class CarEnumData (
    val brand: BrandEnum,
    val model: ModelEnum,
    val colors: List<ColorEnum>
)

enum class BrandEnum { FORD }
enum class ModelEnum { FIESTA, FOCUS }
enum class ColorEnum { RED, BLUE, YELLOW }
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is to **group** your `RawCarEnumData`s by brand and model, and then **reduce** each list of `RawCarEnumData`s into one `CarEnumData`. One way to do this would be the following (like Ivo Beckers answer but in Java):

```
rawCarEnumDataList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(car -> Map.entry(car.brand, car.model)))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .map(
        list ->
            new CarEnumData(
                list.get(0).brand,
                list.get(0).model,
                list.stream().map(RawCarEnumData::color).distinct().toList()))
    .toList();
```

Breaking it down, the `Collectors.groupingBy` gives you a map with keys given by applying a function, and a list of all values that corresponds to that key. Then we pick out the values from this map (giving us a collection of lists of `RawCarEnumData`) and map each list to a `CarEnumData` using the first `RawCarEnumData` for the brand and model, and collecting distinct colors from all the `RawCarEnumData`s.

You didn't mention which Java version you use, if using an older version you may have to use `collect(Collectors.toList())` and some other way to create the group key.

A slightly fancier way to go about would be to use `Collectors.teeing` introduced in Java 12:

```
final var result =
    rawCarEnumDataList.stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                car -> Map.entry(car.brand, car.model),
                Collectors.teeing(
                    toList(),
                    Collectors.mapping(car -> car.color, toSet()),
                    (list, colors) ->
                        new CarEnumData(
                            list.get(0).brand, list.get(0).model, List.copyOf(colors)))))
        .values();
```